# Почему у меня не получается выделять текст alert?

Tags: javascript

Если значение alert записано в одну строчку(пример 1), то текст можно выделить мышью.
Почему если значение alert записано более, чем в одну строчку(пример 2), то не получается выделить текст мышью?

Пример 1:

```js
    let guestList = "Guests: John, Pete, Mary";
    alert(guestList);
```

Пример 2:

```js
    let guestList = "Guests:\n * John\n * Pete\n * Mary";
    alert(guestList);
```

Comment: Пишите в console, там всё выделяется)

Comment: А зачем вам нужен выделение? Ведь Функция alert() предназначена для вывода в браузере предупреждающего модального диалогового окна с некоторым сообщением и кнопкой «ОК». При его появлении дальнейшее выполнение кода страницы прекращается до тех пор, пока пользователь не закроет это окно. Кроме этого, оно также блокирует возможность взаимодействия пользователя с остальной частью страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что нашел на просторах [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591559/how-to-copy-text-of-alert-box/17591662)

> I've found that, in Chrome at least, the alert box text is in fact
> selectable -- when the text does not contain any line-breaks (ie.
> "\n").
>
> I don't know why this is the case, but I've had to use this trick
> before for quick selection prompts. (you could also use prompt("please
> press ctrl+c to copy the text below", "text to copy"), but that
> usually looks worse)

Указанная проблема касается только Chrome. Проверял на FireFox там все нормально.

А вот тут на [комюнити](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/9959602?hl=en) тоже о том же говорят